# how to post objects from angular to a webapi controller

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am creating a pdf using pdfsharp. I need to pass the chart legend data(name,color) to the pdfsharp controller. I am using a angular $http post, a ajax post would be fine as well. the error I am getting is

```
Request URL:http://localhost:46691/api/exportChartPdf/[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]
```

do i need to some how pass it as a string? if so how would I parse it in the api controller back to the way I need it?

the objects i am trying to pass back

```
0: Object
     color: "rgb(67,134,215)"
     name: "Fleming Place - Miscellaneous Spec Builders"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

javascript

```
 var legendModel = $scope.seriesData.map(function (a) {
            return {
                color: a.color,
                name: a.name
            };
        });
        $http.post('/api/exportChartPdf/' + legendModel);
```

api controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public PDF Post() // allow nullable parameter
    {

        try
        {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be posting the object on the form body, not on the querystring.  In addition, your Web API controller should receive a strongly typed object that mirrors the data that you're passing.

```
public class Data
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public PDF Post([FromBody]List<Data> data) 
{
    ... 
}
```

And then simply post the object.

```
var legendModel = $scope.seriesData.map(function (a) {
        return {
            color: a.color,
            name: a.name
        };
    });

$http.post('/api/exportChartPdf/', legendModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your controller action is missing parameter on it,

```
[HttpPost]
public PDF Post(SomeClass legendModel) // allow nullable parameter
{

    try
    {
```

SomeClass would contain  `color` & `name` properties.
Then you should correct your `$http.post` call, pass 2nd param as data in JSON format.

```
$http.post('/api/exportChartPdf', { legendModel: legendModel);
```